# Ninject.Extensions.Conventions Inject Singletons in Lists binding on Interface and BaseClass

Tags: c#, binding, singleton, ninject

I got the following testcase that will fail with:

> Expected: same as ArxScriptsTests.Engines.Ioc.Examples+A But was: 
>   ArxScriptsTests.Engines.Ioc.Examples+A

The question is, how to get it right?

```
[TestFixture]
public class Examples
{
    public interface IInterface
    {

    }

    public abstract class BaseClass : IInterface
    {

    }

    public class A : BaseClass
    {

    }

    public class B : BaseClass
    {

    }


    [Test]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();

        // Bind to self
        kernel.Bind(x => x
            .FromThisAssembly()
            .SelectAllClasses().InheritedFrom<BaseClass>()
            .BindToSelf()
            .Configure(b => b.InSingletonScope())
            );

        // Bind to IInterface
        kernel.Bind(x => x
            .FromThisAssembly()
            .SelectAllClasses().InheritedFrom<IInterface>()
            .BindSelection((type, baseTypes) => new List<Type> { typeof(IInterface) })
            .Configure(b => b.InSingletonScope())
            );


        // Bind to BaseClass
        kernel.Bind(x => x
            .FromThisAssembly()
            .SelectAllClasses().InheritedFrom<BaseClass>()
            .BindSelection((type, baseTypes) => new List<Type> { typeof(BaseClass) })
            .Configure(b => b.InSingletonScope())
            );




        List<IInterface> byInterface = new List<IInterface>(kernel.GetAll<IInterface>());
        List<BaseClass> byBaseClass = new List<BaseClass>(kernel.GetAll<BaseClass>());


        Assert.AreSame(byInterface[0], byBaseClass[0]);
    }
}
```

**One Solution would be**

```
[Test]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();

    // Bind to Both
    kernel.Bind(x => x
        .FromThisAssembly()
        .SelectAllClasses().InheritedFrom<IInterface>()
        .BindSelection((type, baseTypes) => new List<Type> { typeof(IInterface), typeof(BaseClass) })
        .Configure(b => b.InSingletonScope())
        );


    List<IInterface> byInterface = new List<IInterface>(kernel.GetAll<IInterface>());
    List<BaseClass> byBaseClass = new List<BaseClass>(kernel.GetAll<BaseClass>());


    Assert.AreSame(byInterface[0], byBaseClass[0]);
}
```

**But** that will not help when I try to put both bindings in different modules. Or is that a bad idea anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Scopes are defined for bindings. There is no way two bindings can share the scope.

What you should do:

1. Use an interface instead of `BaseClass`
2. Fins a coding convention to define what type of calsses are singeltons. e.g. special naming like ending in Service
3. Bindind them using BindAllInterfaces

When using conventions this shouldn't be done from a consumer perspective but from the service provider perspective. So there is no need to have bindings for different interface types in different modules.

Comment: I dont like to extract the BaseClass Interface to just get the DI working. So my Posted solution works even with an Interface and BaseClass. I just have to rethink about my Modules. In fact my BaseClass is "BaseSpellInfo" and the Interface is "ILearnable". So there is a Learning System (Module) that handles everything that can be learned (not only spells) and there are SpellInfos that describe Spells and should be Singletons. If I define them in two modules I will always get two Instances of each SpellInfo, on in the context of Learning and one in the Context of Casting the spell.